# How to mitigate damage from a database dump?

Tags: encryption, hash, databases, data-leakage, sensitive-data-exposure

Is there any good practice to mitigate potential damage from a potential database dump?

I know the best practice is to not store any data at all, but we know that there is always sensitive data to be saved.

For things like password, we can potentially get away by using bcrypt or PBKDF2 hash. But what about other informations like address, credit card, medical information? We can encrypt them inside the database, but that will also make them not searchable. Does it actually even make sense to encrypt stuff to the fields in the database?

Some also suggested that to actually shard the database to multiple ones in different location. Does this make sense? If one is compromised, most likely to dump the other ones will be quite straightforward isn't it?

The more I think about it, there is nothing really which can mitigate the damage from a database dump except not storing information and preventing it from actually to happen in the first place. Is it really so?

Comment: See also [Building Searchable Encrypted Databases with PHP and SQL](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct encrypting the data at the application layer and storing it in the database has limitation on search, although clever application architecture could get around some of this by allowing a temporary decryption of data while the application is running, such as in memory - depends on the size of dataset, the security requirements, and compliance levels needed.

I think the shard option as you likely indicate doesn't offer much if any protection, and can complicate the system with little benefit.

How about full database encryption options? These are handled by the database engine and are transparent to the application: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde

Comment: but full database encryption doesn't protect from a dump right? correct me if I am wrong, but full database encryption only helps if someone break into your server and takes away your harddrive, which is hardly the issue on cloud environment nowdays.

Comment: Good point. It will help with compliance though such as PCI-DSS issues. How about hashing the values, in addition to encryption, in a seperate column in the DB, you can use this for searching. Clearly this is no good for complex fields or partial searches, and leaves other issues like rainbow attacks. I guess this is a classic security vs convenience issue.

Comment: "temporary decyption of data" makes range based queries impossible without a full table scan.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption is good idea. But its a question, how the attacker will be able to dump the DB. If over the application which encrypt / decrypt it would have no any effect. Full DB encryption, as you correctly said, is just protection against internal attacks.

Regarding card data, there are exact requirements you have to follow if you would like to store, so called, Card Holder Data. If you would like to pass the certification it is quiet high probability you will be asked to use Harware Security Module in dependency what kind of the data you would like to process and store. If you can avoid it I would recommend to not store them at all and be out of scope of PCI DSS standard.

As far as I know there is no any good protection scheme against the DB dump while it would be still easily possible to operate it, make searches and so on.

Its better to think about how it can happen the DB would be dumped and protect the DB (whole environment) against it. And this would require much more lines of writing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you develop your globally distributed, sharded, salted, hashed, encrypted and indexed solution. Your data is stored as a series of tokenized SHA256 hashes in row-encrypted key-value tables spread across datacenters worldwide, all of which are firewalled off from each other, and all of which run full-disk encryption.

- Nobody can log into a single server and just dump the data.
- Nobody can just yank a hard drive and walk off with the data.
- Even if they did, they'd get arbitrary data ('1568de12b5c51ac272fcd9112b5c9' : '2b472568deac272fcd9112b5c51880f0ac443d1c').

What exactly do you propose to do with what you've stored?

Whatever mechanism you develop to search, retrieve and decrypt the data for your business case will become the vector by which your system will be compromised. It will probably be the result of social engineering or malware introduced via social engineering. Someone with access divulges their credentials in a phishing email, or some call center rep fails to authenticate a caller before fulfilling their request.

All of your security controls can be negated by the fact that an algorithm now exists to get material data out of your haystack.

So, how to mitigate? Don't overcomplicate your architecture. It won't save you in the end and all you'll be left with is an unusable nightmare.

Just implement sane controls and fortify your weakest links.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, passwords can be hashed. Sometimes data needs to be ligged which will rarely (if ever) need to be read, here asymmetric encryption using a public key (with the corresponding private key held offline) may be a solution - but typically data of this type has a very low asset value. Everything else needs to be readable.

That means that the application needs the means to decrypt the data. So unless you have backdoors into your database, the route to the (encrypted) data also provides access to the keys (or the clear text). It might impress your shareholders to hear that you encrypt all your data with 256 bit AES, but it's no benefit if the clear text is still retrievable via an SQL injection attack. Database encryption has at least 20% performance overhead (in some cases much, much higher). Most people have a finite budget for security and I suggest that its better to spend that time and money on protecting the attack surface.

Note that database (or application level) data encryption (which I assume you are talking about) is quite different from file and block device encryption - which protects against unwanted access to your physical media. This has a much lower, and consistent performance overhead. Many dbms provide file encryption (often described as *full* database encryption) and I would consider this essential if you do not control the storage infrastructure; the filesystem is then potentially part of the attack surface.